# Regex not working on google chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I have this regex:

```
function removeNonGold(input){
    var price = input.value
    var id = input.id
    price = price.replace("^?\d+(\.\d{1})?",'')
    document.getElementById(id).value = price
}
```

that works over this input field:

```
<input class="form-control" onkeyup="removeNonGold(this)" min="0.01" step="0.01" lang="nb" type="number" name="service[promote_price]" id="service_promote_price">
```

It should remove any characters that are not numbers or dots.

It works fine on Safari and Firefox but it keep removing the dots at chrome.

Comment: that's not a RegExp, that's a string ...

Comment: you want `price = price.replace(/^?\d+(\.\d{1})?/,'')` ... unless `price` isn't a string but some Object you've created that has a specific replace function

Comment: Although, the input above does not allow non-numeric input in chrome by default, so I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I would be very surprised if that works in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: You may try the following regex: [`price = price.replace(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|./g, '$1')`](https://regex101.com/r/aU3wE2/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the character set `[^\d.]` for your regex. That will match, as desired, "any characters that are not numbers or dots." Here's how to use it:

```
price = price.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
```

Comment: even using this regex chrome ease everything when i type a point.